# shortcut of website on home screen in android

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm trying to make a website's shortcut and I'm also confuse how to make my question. 
I'm using the following code but when I click on my app under the app section of the phone it gives me only a blank page but I found that it is making a shortcut on the home screen.

Is there any way to make the shortcut on the app section like other webpages for example: gmail, and the second thing I want that the webpage should not use any browser again like the gmail icon when we click it open webpages and don't use the browser.
I really need help and forgive me if my question is not clear. Thanks in advance

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com"));


    Intent installer = new Intent();
    installer.putExtra("android.intent.extra.shortcut.INTENT", i);
    installer.putExtra("android.intent.extra.shortcut.NAME", "facebook");
    installer.putExtra("android.intent.extra.shortcut.ICON_RESOURCE", "I THINK this is a bitmap"); //can also be ignored too
    installer.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    sendBroadcast(installer);


}
```

manifest file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry I misunderstood at first. One way to solve the problem is to just make a launcher activity that searches for an app to handle a url intent like so:

```
 String url = getString(R.string.facebook_url);
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
 startActivity(i);
```

This is a bit of an odd thing to do though depending on your use case. Remember You can have multiple launcher activities so you could add this in and it wouldn't interfere with your main app. However, it's probably NOT something you actually want to release in production as users wouldn't like it.

Comment: Thanks for understanding my problem. Could you please tell me how should I pass the url in the string here.                       String url = getString(R.string."www.facebook.com");

Comment: you could simply hardcode the string. String url = "facebok.com"; 
what i was suggesting would require you to put a facebook_url in the strings.xml file in the project. You can do it either way. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand can you show me how to use in strings.xml  file. actually I'm new to java and android.